# Failing disk on Windows Server 2008 combined with boot problems, how to solve?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Ok, I really hope that someone can help me out here. I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 at Hetzner. It is configured in Raid 1, however the server has turned out to have some problems and will now only boot the secondary plesk installation. I had Hetzner test the disks and one of them is failing. However if I use F8 during startup and boot directly on the second disk, i am not able to boot.

I am guessing that disk 1 is failing, however the boot partition is working fine. Disk 2 is working, however something is wrong with the boot partition.

This is sort of the current status of the Raid system:

[See the current raid status in this image](http://content.screencast.com/users/mkongsfelt/folders/Jing/media/f25701da-63ba-4ace-afbd-88b6f77c1031/2014-05-02_2058.png)

The issue now is, that i somehow need to make it possible to boot the second disk, in order to replace the first disk.

I really hope, that someone can help me in the right direction, to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a chance to experiment with a RAID1 Windows XP computer with two drives that failed to boot with a BSOD. Since they are RAID1 each disk can be worked on independently of the other.  I pulled the drives and mounted them one at a time in an external SATA to USB housing and backed up the data I wanted from each drive.  I compared the two separate backups and they were identical.  Then I re-installed the two drives in the original machine and broke the RAID in the system controller setup. I ignored the dire warnings about losing all the data because I already got what I wanted.  I booted up the machine and it worked fine with two identical drives C and D.

In your case you can simply try unplugging one of the two drives and see if will boot on the other drive.  It should boot with only one drive installed (the good bootable drive).  If the machine won't boot with the one drive then unplug it and plug in the other one and try booting off that one.